# Showing/Hiding Box inside ngFOR

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to show/hide boxes inside a `ngFor` but I'm getting an error. The first item works well, but the second one I get a undefined error.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
>       at CardComponent.push../src/app/shared/card/card.component.ts.CardComponent.showBox (card.component.ts:78)

**Main HTML**

```
<div class="col s12 l6 xl4" *ngFor="let student of students | async; let i = index">
   <app-card [student]="student" [i]="i"></app-card>
</div>
```

**card component HTML**

```
<div class="card card-min">
  <div class="card-content no-padding">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="col s12 no-padding">
          <div class="card travel-info col s12 no-padding" style="top:0!important; left:0!important; display: none;"
          #travelInfoBox>
          <p>{{ i }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m6 l6 no-padding" (click)="showBox(student.studentID, i)">
          <div class="arr-dep-btn-outline">
            <div class="icon i-outline">
              <i class="material-icons small">flight_land</i>
            </div>
            <div class="txt">
              <p class="arr-dep-flag" *ngIf="!isPast">Arrival</p>
              <p class="arr-dep-flag" *ngIf="isPast">Arrived</p>
              <p class="date-stamp">{{ student.dateArrival | date }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="chev" *ngIf="!isPast">
              <i class="material-icons small">chevron_right</i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m6 l6 no-padding" (click)="showBox(student.studentID, i)">
          <div class="arr-dep-btn-outline">
            <div class="icon i-outline">
              <i class="material-icons small">flight_takeoff</i>
            </div>
            <div class="txt">
              <p class="arr-dep-flag" *ngIf="!isPast">Departure</p>
              <p class="arr-dep-flag" *ngIf="isPast">Departured</p>
              <p class="date-stamp">{{ student.dateDeparture | date }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="chev" *ngIf="!isPast">
              <i class="material-icons small">chevron_right</i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**card.component.ts**

```
@ViewChildren('travelInfoBox') travelInfoBox: QueryList<ElementRef>;

showBox(studentID, i) {
    const nel = this.travelInfoBox.toArray();
    const nativeElement = nel[i].nativeElement;
    nativeElement.style.display = nativeElement.style.display === 'none' || !nativeElement.style.display ? 'block' : 'none';
    this.getData(studentID);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

card.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('travelInfoBox', { read: ElementRef }) private travelInfoBox: ElementRef;

showBox(studentID) {
  const nativeElement = this.travelInfoBox.nativeElement;
  nativeElement.style.display = nativeElement.style.display ? 'block' : 'none';
  this.getData(studentID);
}
```

html

```
<div class="card travel-info col s12 no-padding" style="top:0!important; left:0!important; display: none;" #travelInfoBox>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also include the code that builds the element with id = travelInfoBox? It looks like there is only 1 travelInfoBox in the html you posted, not two.

Comment: Hey @tcigrand after reading your comment you triggered something, the card is the element that's getting repeated on the loop, so it will always have only one `#travelInfoBox`.  No it's sorta works. My issue now is, I can click on the second card and everything will work fine, but it will not work when I click on the first one. I will edit the code to see if you can shine a light on this :)

Comment: Will it be possible to create a Sample StackBlitz replicating this issue? There are some missing pieces in the code that I can't seem to figure out. You're using routing for instance but haven't added a route config. Plus I'm not sure which component you're using as a part to the card component. And things of this sort.